# toggle Textview image with each click

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a TextView whose accompanying image I want to toggle with each click/pressed action. So if it's img_1 and the user clicks, it should switch to img_2; if the user clicks the textview again, then it should turn to img_1; and so on. I don't know how to apply the following to my end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_blue"/>

</selector>
```

right now it would only change very briefly to red on pressed and then immediately return to blue so that blue is the usual color.

Comment: Use state_selected="true" and do view.setSelected(true) in the onClick callback for that TextView

Comment: You could just toggle a `boolean`/`int` flag and change according to `true`/`false` or `0`/`1`

Comment: @VasilySochinsky actually it does work. do you mind posting as response

Comment: accept the solution if it works, otherwise tell me why not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way will be using selector responsive for `state_selected` and manually toggling the selection state in the onClick listener for your textView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_red" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico_blue"/>

</selector>
```

And in your java code:

```
yourTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
        }
    });
```